# Is it possible to DRY up overloaded function a signature which uses generics?

Tags: typescript, generics, overloading

I am writing a simple Axios wrapper function which incorporates zod-parsing and returns a discriminated union for more pleasant error-handling. In some cases, the default behaviour of Axios should be preserved where it should throw any errors, I've successfully implemented this through overloading by passing `{ throw: true }` to the `config` parameter. What I don't like is the verbosity of the implementation. Is there a way to make below overloading more DRY? Ideally declaring the generics `Schema` and `Parsed` once instead of duplicating them three times?

```
import type { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
import * as z from 'zod';
import * as URLS from '~/constants/api-url-constants';
import { coerceError } from '~/utils';

type Result<T> = { ok: true; response: T } | { ok: false; error: Error };
type Url = string | ((urls: typeof URLS) => string);

interface Config<Schema extends z.Schema, Throw extends boolean>
  extends AxiosRequestConfig {
  schema?: Schema | ((zod: typeof z) => Schema);
  throw?: Catch;
}

/**
 * Axios wrapper which accepts Zod-schema to parse
 * response data and return typed response inferred from schema's output type.
 * Schema validations happens in `config.transformResponse`,
 * meaning that failed Zod parsing is able to be intercepted.
 *
 * Returns discriminated union by default for error handling.
 * Use overload `config.catch` to throw unsuccessful api-call like native axios.
 */
async function axiosWrapper<
  Schema extends z.Schema = z.ZodUnknown,
  Parsed = z.output<Schema>,
>(url: Url, config: Config<Schema, false>): Promise<Result<Parsed>>;

async function axiosWrapper<
  Schema extends z.Schema = z.ZodUnknown,
  Parsed = z.output<Schema>,
>(url: Url, config: Config<Schema, true>): Promise<Parsed>;

async function axiosWrapper<
  Schema extends z.Schema = z.ZodUnknown,
  Parsed = z.output<Schema>,
>(url: Url, config: Config<Schema, boolean>): Promise<Result<Parsed> | Parsed> {
  // …implmentation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to decrease the number of generics you have to write, and in general to remove duplicated code here. However, it will also change how you use the function.

For example, the following would work:

```
type AxiosWrapperFunction<
  Schema extends z.Schema = z.ZodUnknown,
  Parsed = z.output<Schema>
> = {
  (url: Url, config: Config<Schema, false>): Promise<Result<Parsed>>;
  (url: Url, config: Config<Schema, true>): Promise<Parsed>;
};

export const createAxiosWrapper = <
  Schema extends z.Schema = z.ZodUnknown,
  Parsed = z.output<Schema>
>(): AxiosWrapperFunction<Schema, Parsed> => {
  return (url: Url, config: Config<Schema, boolean>) => {
    /** implementation */
  };
}
```

In this scenario, we must create a wrapper function because it has to be possible to pass generics to the implementation function as well.

The drawback is, that we must now use the function as follows:

```
const axiosWrapper = createAxiosWrapper</** your generics */>();

axiosWrapper(/** your arguments */)
```

Instead of being able to do:

```
axiosWrapper</** your generics */>(/** your arguments */)
```

My advice would be to keep rewriting the generics and stick to your implementation of function overloading

Comment: insightful, thanks! Hmm yeah, in that case it would seem that it's fine for now, but I'll remember this pattern for a generic-overload-situation that gets more out of hand.